# Visual studio build error 2015 using microsoft azure sql database v12

Tags: azure

once i am tired to build my project .I am getting build error in the below code.

CREATE PROCEDURE [dlm].[uspScriptTableInsertionForADW]

(

----- - - ----- some code-------

CREATE TABLE #selectColListTable

```
WITH

(



DISTRIBUTION = ROUND_ROBIN
```

)

Error:

SQL80001:Incorrect syntax near 'WITH' .Excepting '(' ,or AS.

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL Database does not support WITH DISTRIBUTION. That is supported in Azure SQL Data Warehouse, but not Azure SQL Database.

Comment: Hi chris , thanks .. but I my issue is how to add data ware house project in VS2015.  If I am creating a  new project means I will have only one option SQL server  database project. so I need to add any add-on . can you please help me.. thanks

Comment: That would be a different question that you asked here. You should open / create a new question on SO asking this specifically.